# Regex code question

Tags: regex

I'm new to this site and don't know if this is the place to ask this question here?

I was wondering if someone can explain the 3 regex code examples below in detail?

Thanks.

Example 1

```
`&([a-z]{1,2})(acute|uml|circ|grave|ring|cedil|slash|tilde|caron|lig);`i
```

Example 2

```
\\1
```

Example 3

```
`[^a-z0-9]`i','`[-]+`
```

Comment: how do I move this question over then?

Answer (score 2):

The first regex looks like it'll match the HTML entities for accented characters (e.g., `&eacute;` is é; `&oslash;` is ø; `&aelig;` is æ; and `&Acirc;` is Â).

To break it down, `&` will match an ampersand (the start of the entity), `([a-z]{1,2})` will match any lowercase letter one or two times, `(acute|uml|circ|grave|ring|cedil|slash|tilde|caron|lig)` will match one of the terms in the pipe-delimited list (e.g., circ, grave, cedil, etc.), and `;` will match a semicolon (the end of the entity). I'm not sure what the `i` character means at the end of the line; it's not part of the regex.

All told, it will match the HTML entities for accented/diacritic/ligatures. Compared, though, to [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp) page, it doesn't seem that it matches all of the valid entities (although ti does catch many of them). Unless you run in case-insensitive mode, the `[a-z]` will only match lowercase letters. It will also never match the entities `&eth;` or `&thorn;` (ð, þ, respectively) or their capital versions (Ð, Þ, also respectively).

---

The second regex is simpler. `\1` in a regex (or in regex find-replace) simply looks for the contents of the first capturing group (denoted by parentheses `()`) and (in a regex) matches them or (in the replace of a find) inserts them. What you have there `\\1` is the `\1`, but it's probably written in a string in some other programming language, so the coder had to escape the backslash with another backslash.

---

For your third example, I'm less certain what it does, but I can explain the regexes. `[^a-z0-9]` will match any character that's not a lowercase letter or number (or, if running in case-insensitive mode, anything that's not a letter or a number). The caret (`^`) at the beginning of the character class (that's anything inside square brackets `[]`) means to negate the class (i.e., find anything that is not specified, instead of the usual find anything that is specified). `[-]+` will match one or more hyphens (`-`). I don't know what the `i','` between the regexes means, but, then, you didn't say what language this is written in, and I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: The `i` at the end of the first regex may be an improperly formatted case-insensitive modifier.

Comment: It looks like the examples are incomplete.  If you add an apostrophe to the beginning and end of each example, they become well-formed regexes as they would appear in PHP source code (or, in the third example, a *pair* of regexes separated by a comma).  The apostrophes are the *string* delimiters, and the grave accents are the *regex* delimiters.